# Need to import non ES6 library without export to VueJS

Tags: javascript, import, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a strange problem to solve. 
In a future VueJS project we need to use a library which is quite outdatet but there is no time to rewrite it.

It is a JS file containing a lot of silly var's declared, some functions and prototypes.

It is mainly structured like this:

```
var t1 = 'test1';
var i1 = 2;
function testclass(arg) {
  object1 = this;
  this._t1 = null;
  return object1;
}
testclass.prototype = {
  dosth: function () {
    console.log('doing');
  }
}
```

But its about 10.399 Lines of code so no way of rewriting it to a object or integrating export to each function.

Do you guys have any good idea or tool to manage this problem.
The only whay until now would be to import it seperatly as script tag but then our linter would cry and it also would look quite ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Use eslint cli and run it with the `--fix` flag. This can fix a lot of these issues with the linter. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-from-jscs#--fix

Other than stylistic changes and es6 syntactic sugar, it will work just fine in the browser, so there's no need to rewrite anything.